# Auto suggestion icon in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

[image]

Does anyone know what the icon ">>" (*two blue arrows*) stands for?

I couldn't find the icon listed on [Symbols Reference - JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/symbols.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two blue arrows tell you that the Class (or interface etc.) has already been imported for use. So in this case you have `use` statements for `Illuminate\Http\Request` and `App\Http\Requests` and `App\Http\Controllers\Controller` so they are marked with the double arrow symbol. The other classes in the autocomplete list have not been added with a use statement.